# how to add a shape divider in vuetify.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `vuetify` and I'm trying to add a shape divider like what I've shown in the picture, but I'm unable to do it.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

You need to do that with HTML and CSS.
There is some ways.

1. It would be done with a background image
2. Another way is a svg file and css
3. Do it with css transform

You can check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/ZEpEPGK)

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9d2f, #ff6126);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}

.divider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  /* drop the height to have a constant angle for all screen widths */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
  <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/t-517/divider-triangle.png" class="divider" />
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```

to get Idea how to make it as 2nd way .

and this one [codepen](https://codepen.io/erikdkennedy/pen/EZozpV) for make it with css transform(third way).

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9d2f, #ff6126);
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__bg"></div>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```